# .Htaccess for mobile redirect. With a twist

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having issues with proper redirection to and from mobile websites using htaccess. Since I'm incapable to grasp htaccess principles I thought wiser people could help.

Desktop users go to www.website.com while mobile users- to m.website.com.

Right now we're redirecting with js and php, but that leads to bad nalytics tracking, so I need to do whole redirect thing using htaccess.

But there's a twist in this case: website has different languages which has to be dealt with htaccess as well.

Here are some possible cases:
website.com > www.website.com/en/ (note www and language identifier added)

etc. you get the idea. This should work backwards as well - if visitors is trying to open mobile link, he should be redirected to www. version. Plus, if user is already opening link with language identifier set, script should be able to to handle www. or m. part. and vice versa.

Since we are using same structure and content for both versions but on different subdomains we could use 2 htaccess files, or one- which ever works.

We were able to sort this but only for top most level links, so www.website.com/en/more-stuff didn't do a thing.

Comment: Show code that you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, can't do. I cought myself in a bit of a rage last night and went back to previous backup and didn't save that version :/